# cambiar href onclick con un botón

Tags: javascript, html

Este código me sirve para cambiar de *link* (entre dos páginas), necesito que se cambie el *link* entre uno y otro cada vez que se haga *click* al mismo botón , intenté haciendo una función aparte pero no logro cambiar los *links* con el mismo botón:

```html
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Href(){
    document.getElementById('enlace').innerHTML=" Google"
    document.getElementById('enlace').href="http://www.google.com"
}


</script>
</head>

<body>
    <a id="enlace" href="https://espanol.yahoo.com/">yahoo es</a>
    <form>
        <input type="button" onclick="Href()" value="cambiar url y texto">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A ver si entendi. Si le doy el primer clic, debe de cambiar a google.com y luego al dar otro clic debe de cambiar a yahoo.com otra vez y asi por el estilo?

Answer (score 6):

Otra opción es utilizar expresiones terniarias y una simple comparación

```html
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Href(){
///Si el texto es "Yahoo" lo cambiamos por "Google", si no es que es "Google" y lo cambiamos por "Yahoo". Lo mismo para el enlace
    document.getElementById('enlace').innerHTML= document.getElementById('enlace').innerHTML=="Yahoo" ? " Google" : "Yahoo";
    
   document.getElementById('enlace').href= document.getElementById('enlace').href=="https://es.yahoo.com/" ? "http://www.google.com" : "https://es.yahoo.com/"
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <a id="enlace" href="https://espanol.yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a>
    <form>
        <input type="button" onclick="Href()" value="cambiar url y texto">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Deberías agregar un flag o bandera para que cambie por uno o por otro el valor del href y texto. Y en vez de generar un botón para que haga ese cambio, lo aplicás al link la función del `onClick`. Por ejemplo:

```js
// este es un flag booleano inicializado en true
var flag = true;

// función para obtener los cambios
function Href() {
  var element = document.getElementById('enlace');
  if (flag) {
    element.innerHTML = " Google";
    element.href = "http://www.google.com";
  } else {
    element.innerHTML = " Stackoverflow";
    element.href = "https://es.stackoverflow.com";
  }
  // cambio el valor del flag
  flag = !flag;
}
```

```html
<!-- Aquí agrego la función del `onClick`-->

  <a id="enlace" href="https://espanol.yahoo.com/" onClick="Href()">yahoo es</a>
```

Comment: La pregunta menciona que se debe hacer un cambio al hacer clic en un botón pero tu código no incluye el botón.

Answer (score 4):

Si lo que deseas es alternar la url por cada clic, otra alternativa es utilizando un array donde tendras 2 url. Luego por cada clic le haces un `reverse()` al array, esto lo que hace es que invierte los elementos. Luego le asignas el primer indice y listo.

```js
var urls = [
  {text: "Yahoo ES", url: "http://www.yahoo.com"},
  {text: "Google", url: "http://www.google.com"}
];
function Href(){
    var data = urls.reverse()[0]; // el dice 0 pasa al indice 1 y viceversa.
    document.getElementById('enlace').innerHTML= data.text;
    document.getElementById('enlace').href= data.url;
}
```

```html
<a id="enlace" href="https://espanol.yahoo.com/">Yahoo ES</a>
<form>
    <input type="button" onclick="Href()" value="cambiar url y texto">
</form>
```

Asi lo hacemos las simple sin necesidad de `if` y `flags`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var intercambiar = (e, links) => {
 let temp = 0;
 
 document.getElementById(e).onclick = _ => {
 
 document.getElementById("webLink").innerHTML = 
 temp === 0 ? (temp++, links[temp]) 
            : (temp--, links[temp]);
 };
};

intercambiar("cambiar",["https://google.com","https://website.com"]);
```

```html
<input id="cambiar" type="button" value="Cambiar">
<b id="webLink"></b>
```

Comment: Hola Eduardo Sebastian, esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Edítala para añadir algo más de detalle: ¿qué hace el código? ¿Cómo soluciona el problema expuesto en la pregunta?